# Get text from a section of a pdf page with IcePdf

Tags: java, pdf, text, icepdf

I'm writing some java classes to test some libraries about the issue to extract text of a portion of a pdf page. I tested iText and PDFBox. Now I want to write a class using IcePdf, but I don't know how to do because I can [extract the full page text](http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/PDF/Extracting+Text) and not a specific portion.

Can someone help me?

Comment: How are you identifying what specific portion this is? Provide some examples, may be able to help :-)

Comment: @Reginald I tried to use a `Rectangle` object of awt to describe the area to read, this way works very well with PdfBox and Itext but not with IcePdf. With IcePdf I don't make the same thing, because I don't find a method to pass a section to read.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting text in a specific region of PDF page using ICEpdf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854969/extracting-text-in-a-specific-region-of-pdf-page-using-icepdf)